# Clearing Large Apache Domain Logs

Tags: linux, apache

I am having an issue where Apache logs are growing out of proportion on several servers (Linux CentOS 5)... I will eventually disable logging completely but for now I need a quick fix to reclaim the hard disk space.

I have tried using the `echo " " > /path/to/log.log` or the `* > /path/to/log.log` but they take too long and almost crash the server as the logs are as large as 100GB

Deleting the files works fast but my question is, will it cause a problem when I restart apache. My servers are live and full of users so I can't crash them.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: `>/path/to/log.log` will make the file empty.

Comment: You should never disable logging. You'll need that info someday. Just turn on logrotate. It'll solve the issue while still giving you recent logs for stats and forensics.

Answer (score 23):

Use the [truncate](http://man.cx/truncate%281%29) command

```
truncate -s 0 /path/to/log.log
```

In the longer term you should use [logrotate](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-rotate-log-files/) to keep the logs from getting out of hand.

Comment: You seem to know exactly what you are talking about but just to reiterate, this truncate command should not require huge amounts of CPU to truncate the file... as previous attempts as mentioned before were not quite pleasant... Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cat /dev/null > /path/to/log.log
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 mv /path/to/log.log /path/to/log.log.1
```

Do this for your access, error and if you are *really* doing it on prod, you rewrite logs.
This doesn't effect Apache on *nix, since the file is open.  Then restart Apache.  Yes, I know I said restart, but this usually takes a second or so, so I doubt that anyone will notice -- or blame it on the network.  The restarted Apache will be running with a new set of log files.

In terms of your current logs, IMO you need to keep *at least* the last 3 months error logs, and 1 month access logs, but look at your volumetrics to decide your rough per week volumes for error and access logs.  *Don't* truncate the old files.  If necessary do a nice tail piped to `gzip -c` of these to archives.  If you want to split the use a loop doing a tail|head|gzip using the `--bytes=nnG` option.  OK, you'll split across the odd line but that's better than deleting the lot as you suggest.

Of course, you could just delete the lot as you and others propose, but what are you going to do if you've realised that the site has been hacked recently?  "Sorry: too late; I've deleted the evidence!"

Then for goodness sake implement a logrotate regime.