# How to free space on hard drive after improperly deleted logs

Tags: bash, ssh, debian

"""I want to free space on hard drive after improperly deleted logs .(/var/log/apache2/)
Files are deleted but hard drive is still at: 90% USED
With

```
    lsof | grep deleted
```

i see that those files are open but i cant close them (tried killing and restarting apache), how can i fix this situation?"""

**SOLUTION**
Thanks to @123 i know what happend. Logs were hold by web application so restarting apache2 didnt work -> i had to restart application. 
Thank you for help.

Comment: You deleted it as root?

Comment: yes it was deleted with root privileges

Comment: with root you mean `sudo` privileges or after `su -`, as i can see you need to be root to delete these files ... have a look at this http://matthewwittering.com/blog/ubuntu-tips/how-to-remove-apache-logs-&-errors.html

Comment: They were deleted when logged as root i cant see them now in var/log/apache2 directory but they are still open and block hard drive space.

Comment: Try running `sync` command (as root)...

Comment: @123 : The op has already restarted apache

Comment: @TreeFolk : See this SO [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9569433/1620779)

Comment: @sjsam If apache was writing to the logs and you restart it then the file descriptors would be closed. Either they didn't shut down apache, or something else is writing to the log directory which needs to be terminated.

Comment: lsof should also be telling you what process is opening the files ... it probably is not apache because they were killed right ?
So what's keeping the files open ?

Comment: Thanks to @123 i know what happend. Logs were hold by web application so restarting apache2 didnt work -> i had to restart application. Thank you for help.

Comment: @TreeFolk : When apache is not running, try as root `lsof | grep access_log | grep apache2`. It should give you the process using `../apache2/..access_log`.

Comment: @TreeFolk : Consider posting an answer instead of changing the  question title as resolved. :D

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @123 i know what happend. Logs were hold by web application so restarting apache2 didnt work -> i had to restart application.